# Should I throw an ArgumentException?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, msdn, argumentexception

This question is about convention and interpreting MSDN, so I don't think it's primarily opinion based.

I'm wondering about [ArgumentException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception(v=vs.110).aspx): I have a builder class which is used to build a filter object that will be applied when retrieving a set of email messages from a mailbox.  The builder has a number of methods to set the filter options.  For example, I have two methods for setting the "sent date" range of the filter -- sent before XX and/or sent after XX.  I want to add a guard clause to each which will throw an exception if, say, the provided "before" date is *after* the provided "after" date.  I would do this with a common validation method:

```
/// <summary>
/// This class provides methods for validating dates in various ways.
/// </summary>
internal static class DateValidation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Validate the provided "start" and "end" date/time values.
    /// If they do not represent a valid range, throw an exception.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="start">The date/time that represents the start of the range.</param>
    /// <param name="end">The date/time that represents the end of the range.</param>
    internal static void ValidateDateTimeRange(DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
    {
        if (start.HasValue && end.HasValue)
        {
            if (start.Value > end.Value) 
                throw new Exception(
                string.Format(@"The start date/time ""{0}"" " +
                @"occurs after the end date/time ""{1}"".", 
                start.ToString(), end.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the two builder methods:

```
/// <summary>
/// Set a value which represents a date/time after which
/// messages must have been sent to be part of filtered output.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="afterDateTime">The date/time after which
/// messages must have been sent to be part of filtered output.</param>
public void SetSentAfterDateTime(DateTime afterDateTime)
{
    DateValidation.ValidateDateTimeRange(afterDateTime, _sentBeforeDateTime);
    _sentAfterDateTime = afterDateTime;
}

/// <summary>
/// Set a value which represents a date/time before which
/// messages must have been sent to be part of filtered output.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="beforeDateTime">The date/time before which
/// messages must have been sent to be part of filtered output.</param>    
public void SetSentBeforeDateTime(DateTime beforeDateTime)
{
    DateValidation.ValidateDateTimeRange(_sentAfterDateTime, beforeDateTime);
    _sentBeforeDateTime = beforeDateTime;
}
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Most commonly, an ArgumentException is thrown by the common language
>   runtime or another class library and indicates developer error.

I get that the phrase "most commonly" leaves the possibility open for other usages, like mine, but I like to stick to convention.  I'm building a public API, so the exception will be documented and will bubble up beyond the public interface; furthermore, it doesn't "indicate developer error".  It *could* conceivably indicate user error instead (it is a common convention to use exceptions to deal with user input validation issues).  I get the feeling, based on MSDN description, though, that this is not what it is intended for.

> ...Derived classes [ArgumentNullException and
>   ArgumentOutOfRangeException] should be used instead of
>   ArgumentException, except in situations where neither of the derived
>   classes is acceptable. For example, exceptions should be thrown by:
>
> ...
>
> ArgumentOutOfRangeException when the value of an argument is outside
>   the range of acceptable values; for example, when the value "46" is
>   passed as the month argument during the creation of a DateTime.

My argument might be outside the range of acceptable values, but that condition is determined dynamically based on the other date/time value.  There is no static range of values that are "out of range".

So is `ArgumentException` typically used for cases like this?

Comment: I would disagree with the statement `it is a common convention to use exceptions to deal with user input validation issues.`  The developer that is using your API is responsible for validating user input before passing it to your function.  If the user provides invalid input and the developer doesn't catch it before passing it into your function, this is "developer error."

Comment: Good point.  I agree.

Comment: _"This question is about convention and interpreting MSDN, so I don't think it's primarily opinion based"_ -- by asking for anything other than a literal reading of MSDN, you most certainly are asking a "primarily opinion based" question. Conventions are, by definition, subjective, and even where some convention has been documented, if you want individual interpretations of that documentation, to go beyond what's literally being presented in the documentation, that can only be subjective as well.

Comment: Sorry, but this is opinion based, as it falls outside the typical scenario. You could make a case for `ArgumentException`, but also for `InvalidOperationException`. Question is: does it matter? The developer should not catch this exception anyway, but fix the calling program. See also https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kcwalina/2007/01/30/how-to-design-exception-hierarchies/

Comment: Why allow setting "SentAfter" and "SentBefore" separately? Something equivalent to `SetSentAfterSentBefore(Tuple<DateTime,Datetime> times)` in my head makes sense to throw `ArgumentException` because "the" argument passed in is invalid, whereas `SetSentAfterSentBefore(DateTime before, DateTime after)` it doesn't make sense to throw argument exception unless the datetime's are null. If the two times are coupled (which they are), then why keep them completely separate? I say couple them explicitly and allow them to be separated, don't keep them as entirely separate objects.

Comment: @Quantic -- Because having only a "before" is valid (i.e. "all messages before XX, with no "after" date).  Or vice versa

Comment: @Dan -- no, the static range of variables in that case would be the number of days in a given month.  That's what defines when the value is out of range.  I'm simply saying, I don't have a static range to compare values to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [How to Design Exception Hierarchies](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kcwalina/2007/01/30/how-to-design-exception-hierarchies/) by Krzysztof Cwalina:

> A usage error is something that can be avoided by changing the code that calls your routine.

Let's agree that this is a usage error.

Eric Lippert calls them [Boneheaded exceptions](https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/):

> Boneheaded exceptions are your own darn fault, you could have prevented them and therefore they are bugs in your code. You should not catch them; doing so is hiding a bug in your code.

A developer should not `catch` these types of errors, but change the calling code in order to ensure the exception never happens in the first place. That is why the exact exception type does not matter much.

As Cwalina explains:

> Usage errors need to be communicated to the human developer calling the routine. The exception type is not the best way to communicate errors to humans. The message string is a much better way. Therefore, for exceptions that are thrown as a result of usage errors, I would concentrate on designing a really good (that is explanatory) exception message and using one of the existing .NET Framework exception types: ArgumentNullException, ArgumentException, InvalidOperationException, NotSupportedException, etc. In other words, don’t create new exception types for usage errors because **the type of the exception does not matter for usage errors**. The .NET Framework already has enough types (actually too many, IMHO) to represent every usage error I can think of.

(Emphasis mine)

It doesn't really matter whether you're using an `ArgumentException` or an `InvalidOperationException`. Choose one, but make sure it has a clear `Message`.

Comment: Thank you, this definitely hits the nail on the head.  As I mentioned in my question (which was correctly refuted by BJ Myers), I was thinking the exception could be the result of a user action, but that was wrongheaded.  Given that this is a developer problem, it's definitely a usage error.

Comment: Thanks for the shout-out. FYI the guidelines are: use one of the argument exceptions if the problem is that the argument is wrong. Use an invalid operation exception if *the current state of the object does not permit the desired operation*.  So for example, if you have an object representing a closed pipe, and you attempt to write to the pipe, that's an invalid operation given the state of the object.

Comment: @EricLippert Sure, but here's the thing. You first set the "not before" property. Then you set the "not after" property, and they are incompatible. Is that because of the value you try to set to the "not after" property, or is it because of the state the object is in (because you set the "not before" property first)?

Comment: @KrisVandermotten: Look at it this way. The question to ask is "would changing the value of the argument prevent the exception?" When writing to a closed pipe, no argument works, so it should not be an argument exception. But passing the wrong date could be fixed by passing the right date, so its an argument exception.  The purpose of making this distinction is to make it easier for the developer of the buggy caller to find their bug.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with the accepted answer; I would add to it that if your code puts your caller in a position where it *must* catch an exception in order to determine whether user-supplied data is valid, then you have made what I call a "vexing exception".  It is vexing that you have to make an exception handler to handle a non-exceptional situation. Users entering inconsistent date ranges is not *exceptional*. That's a normal part of the workflow of the program.

Consider solving the problem in the user interface layer.  Implement date pickers so that they don't allow a user to choose date combinations that would produce an exception. There are a number of ways to do so -- gray out dates that are invalid, for example.  Or detect the inconsistency and make the pickers turn red or flash or whatever, and prevent the operation from being committed.

Comment: I agree. In fact, I have been wondering wether this situation should be an _error_ at all. Sure, a query that says "not before Febrary 1 and not after January 1" will return nothing, but is that an error? Maybe it should just be a warning in the UI, or even better, as you point out, the UI should prevent the situation.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but I would like to add that a guard clause should also exist in the business logic layer (the API) to prevent cases where the presentation layer didn't validate.  In such cases, a well-documented exception would be OK in my opinion because -- at that point -- it IS a developer oversight.

Comment: @rory.ap: That's a good idea. Basically this is the approach you have to take in any client-server scenario: the client should send only valid requests, but *the server still has to validate them*. The client could be buggy or hostile.

Comment: Ultimately every operations has to protect itself from outside.  Public API development taught me a hard lesson on that.